# keyserver timed out when trying to add a GPG public key

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gpg

I am trying to add a public key for installing a program with CPG. But I am pretty new to this but every command I found gave me the same error:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
gpg: requesting key 94558F59 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

How is this possible it seems that the I am behind some kind of blockade which makes it impossible to establish a connection to the key server. I looked into many OP questions and tried all commands I could find but nothing worked. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried using another keyserver? hkp://subkeys.pgp.net or hkp://pgp.mit.edu:11371

Comment: @jasonwryan Ive tried the pgp.mit.edu but without hkp:// is the use of that important? i dont believe so but its worth trying for me

Comment: Use the full address, and the alternate port...

Comment: @jasonwryan I still got ?: pgp.mit.edu: Connection timed out
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

Comment: `gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 94558F59` worked for me...

Comment: @jasonwryan The problem is probably caused by a firewall

Comment: Did you try with the alternate port? If so, then you may need to open a port yourself or talk to your sysadmin...

Comment: @jasonwryan i had to use port:80. it now works :)

Comment: In my case was a proxy issue, solved setting the environment variables and [`sudo -E`](https://askubuntu.com/a/102505/349837).

Comment: If firewall is a problem, just specify the port (probably 80 isn't blocked)

apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys ######

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is usually caused by your firewall blocking the port `11371`. You could unblock the port in your firewall. In case you don't have access to the firewall you could:

Force it to use port `80` instead of `11371`

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```

-or alternatively omitting the port-

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Alternatively

- Find and open the key from the key server.
- Copy it's contents into a text file.
- Go to System Tool > Preferences > Software Sources > Authentication > Add key, and select the text file created. **Ubuntu 14.04 and later try**: Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources -> Authentication -> Import key file

Comment: `gpg --import key.txt` if you need to import via command line FYI.

Comment: https://sks-keyservers.net/i/ to download the key FYI

Comment: upvote for alternative way! On Ubuntu 14.04 and later, it's added from `Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources -> Authentication -> Import key file`

Comment: This fixed my issue w/ install the keys for rvm. The following call was hanging for me: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net

Comment: "Find and open the key from the key server." What nobody mentions is how that's done. In my case, the key in question is on gpg.mit.edu. Okay, easy, just go to http://pgp.mit.edu and paste the key into the `Search String` field! Wrong. You must know the magic secret: prepend the key with `0x`. If the key is `0F571F6C`, you must search for `0x0F571F6C`, which is in no way obvious.

Comment: you are the man!! blocked port was my problem.

Comment: I am trying for `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`  & `hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80` but still this error. Why?

Comment: hkp:// was missing from my URL... That resolved my issue.
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys $INSTALL_KEY

Answer (score 26):

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys SOMEKEY
```

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary and, other than that, this answer adds nothing to the poster's problem...

Comment: I was working on this just an hour ago, and adding this line solved the problem for me. There is the difference that I specify port 80 explicitly. I also specify the protocol explicitly. You may be right that sudo is not needed, but my answer does ad a bit of relevant info, don't you think? Oh and, your answer is also correct.

Comment: Remove the sudo and the answer is correct.

Comment: I just checked, and `sudo` is necessary. Sorry.

Comment: Necessary to recieve keys from a public keyserver? I don't think so...

Comment: sudo is only necessary if you're using apt-key. It is definitely not necessary for gpg unless you're trying to update your root keyring. There's nothing special about gpg that requires root.

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary. Heck, if it were, you'd need to `sudo` every time you get an email with a new key, that's stupid.  
There's probably something very broken with your setup (maybe root owns your gpg keyring, since you've been using sudo before).

Comment: Adding the hkp:// as noted in this answer does work for me.

Comment: This is the right answer, I was missing the "hkp:" protocol.

Comment: The combination of `hkp://` prefix and port `:80` suffix receive keys properly - missing either and the timeout problem stays. (no sudo needed though, as noted above)

Answer (score 13):

I encountered same problem when I was trying to add a `GPG` key behind a proxy. The solution to my problem was to [add the `--keyserver-options` in the command](https://askubuntu.com/a/252082/565129):

```
$ sudo apt-key adv \
     --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_URL:PORT/ \
     --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys GPG_KEY
```

Comment: I ended up having to do this even though I already had http_proxy and https_proxy settings in my environment.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AKEYXXX
```

Comment: Removing the port was the solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting your key from another server (worked for me):

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 94558F59
```

or

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem by running the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv \
   --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
   --recv-keys *somekey*
```

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110594/22812) is excellent and after almost 8 year (a long time in security and cryptography), it still works. I thought I’d suggest another alternative that offers greater privacy and security:

#### Use HKPS (HKP over TLS)

This encrypts the connection to the keyserver and helps prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Also, TCP Port 443 is just as unlikely to be blocked by a corporate firewall as Port 80 (unlike Port 11371).

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Note: the URIs, `https://keyserver.ubuntu.com`, `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`, `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443` are all equivalent.

#### Configuring this as the default server

Since the release of GnuPG 2.1.9 (2015-10-09), the `--keyserver` option for `gpg` has been deprecated and users are recommended to “use the `--keyserver` in `dirmngr.conf` instead”. The user’s default keyserver can be configured permanently by editing `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

If the `dirmngr` daemon is already running, you’ll need to run `gpgconf --reload dirmngr` for the new configuration to take effect.

#### System default keyservers

Currently (since versions 2.2.29 and 2.3.2, released in July/August 2021), the GnuPG project has `keyserver.ubuntu.com` configured as its default keyserver if none is specified by the user while Debian (and Ubuntu) packages of `gnupg2` have configured `hkps://keys.openpgp.org` as the default keyserver since `gnupg2 2.2.17-1` (released in 2019).

Note: other answers suggest using [SKS keyserver pools](https://sks-keyservers.net/). Unfortunately, these have suffered privacy and abuse problems and, as of June 2021, are no longer operating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this on one of two identical boxes running ansible deployments against an ubuntu 14.04 image.  In fact, it had previously worked for `app-infra-1` but at some point it began to fail.  The fact that it succeeded on `app-infra-2` freshly recreated suggests it is a corruption on `app-infra-1` or a bug in the detection and reporting of `apt-key adv`.

I tried deleting the key using `apt-key del` but I continue to get the same error.

```
changed: [app-infra-2] => {"changed": true, "item": "", "repo": "ppa:webupd8team/java", "state": "present"}
failed: [app-infra-1] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 7B2C3B0889BF5709A105D03AC2518248EEA14886", "failed": true, "item": "", "rc": 2}
stderr: gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

stdout: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.2zqQuFdBjg --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/puppetlabs-keyring.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 7B2C3B0889BF5709A105D03AC2518248EEA14886

msg: gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

In the end, since it's a vm, my solution was to re-build it with `vagrant`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was required to add ENV statements into my docker file. E.g.

```
ENV  http_proxy "http://[yourproxy]:[port]/"
ENV  https_proxy "http://[yourproxy]:[port]/"
```