# Problem with public key on apt-get update

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gpg

I have Lubuntu 16.04. My problem is similar to [this questiuon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

```
    sudo apt-get update
    Get:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
    Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
    Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
    Hit:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
    Hit:5 http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr debian InRelease                           
    Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                            
    Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [93,3 kB]    
    Fetched 340 kB in 6s (52,6 kB/s)                                               
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
    FB510D557CC3E840
```

Non of answers provided is working:

1. According to [answer #1 of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FB510D557CC3E840
   Executing: /tmp/tmp.oqit2axEyE/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FB510D557CC3E840
   gpg: requesting key 7CC3E840 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
   gpgkeys: key FB510D557CC3E840 not found on keyserver
   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
   gpg: Total number processed: 0
   gpg: keyserver communications error: key not found
   gpg: keyserver communications error: bad public key
   gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad public key
   ```
2. Or this one from [the same question, answer #2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   debian-archive-keyring is already the newest version (2014.3).
   debian-keyring is already the newest version (2016.01.20).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```
3. Or this one from [the same question, answer #3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   debian-archive-keyring is already the newest version (2014.3).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```
4. Or this one from [the same question, answer #4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

   ```
   for n in `ls /var/lib/apt/lists/*gpg`; do echo "$n" ; gpg --list-packets "$n" | grep FB510D557CC3E840; done
   ls: cannot access '/var/lib/apt/lists/*gpg': No such file or directory
   ```
5. Or this one from [the same question, answer #5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   debian-archive-keyring is already the newest version (2014.3).
   debian-keyring is already the newest version (2016.01.20).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```
6. Another try, [answer #1 of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75892/keyserver-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-a-gpg-public-key):

   ```
   gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7CC3E840
   gpg: requesting key 7CC3E840 from keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
   gpgkeys: no keyserver host provided
   gpg: keyserver internal error
   gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
   ```
7. answer number 2 of the same [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75892/keyserver-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-a-gpg-public-key):

   ```
   sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7CC3E840 
   gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/username/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
   gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
   gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
   gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
   ```
8. to be sure there is no problem with permission:

   ```
   ls -l ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
   -rw------- 1 username username 9398 mag 16 15:34 /home/username/.gnupg/gpg.conf
   ```
9. From last [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75892/keyserver-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-a-gpg-public-key):

   ```
   apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  7CC3E840
   Executing: /tmp/tmp.8iRzKu4RVN/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7CC3E840
   gpg: requesting key 7CC3E840 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
   gpgkeys: key 7CC3E840 not found on keyserver
   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
   gpg: Total number processed: 0
   gpg: keyserver communications error: key not found
   gpg: keyserver communications error: bad public key
   gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad public key
   ```

Comment: This has got to be one the best researched questions ever with an amazingly simple answer.  Bugs, bugs, bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing key is the key for the Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository. Following the instructions added to [the website](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) yesterday should fix things:

```
wget http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/pool/debian/extra/su/suldr-keyring_1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i suldr-keyring_1_all.deb
```

(assuming you trust the repository of course!).

Comment: Just curious. How did you figure that out?

Comment: @FaheemMitha SULDR was the only repository where it made sense that the key would be missing; I searched for "key" on the corresponding website, saw the update, downloaded the package, extracted it and ran `gpg --keyring etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/suldr-keyring.gpg -k` which confirmed that the keyring contained the missing key. (It would be nice if `apt-get` mentioned which repository it can't verify because of the missing key...)

Comment: "It would be nice if apt-get mentioned which repository it can't verify because of the missing key..." It would indeed. Is that an outstanding wishlist? If not, someone should report it.

Comment: I asked about this in #debian-apt, and was pointed to https://bugs.debian.org/618445. Apparently this warning isn't meaningful.

Comment: @FaheemMitha much ado about nothing then, that's good to know...